# How to remove this empty space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

codepen link - https://codepen.io/karandixit24/pen/YzrQmdL `

```
    <div class="main-container">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Some of my past projects</h3>
        <div class="post-wrapper">`
```

please help the buddy out!

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know how to help you if we can't see the stylesheets

Comment: That's `top-margin` of the h3 element, you may remove that margin from `h3` or add `overflow: hidden;` to `div.main-container` in order to make it grow to the top margin of its first element.

Comment: Adding overflow: auto worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is caused by the default vertical margin of the h3 element - setting that to 0 removes the offset:

```css
h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You can prevent issues like this by including a reset stylesheet, for example [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). I'd also recommend reading up on this topic, for example [here](https://elad.medium.com/the-new-css-reset-53f41f13282e).